# Flexible box model explanation

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am studying the CSS3 flexible model. I checked out [MDN's page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes) about it I think I got the general concept but I don't understand how the following properties work:

**flex-basis**: The CSS flex-basis property specifies the flex basis which is the initial main size of a flex item.

**flex-grow**: The CSS flex-grow property specifies the flex grow factor of a flex item.

**flex-shrink**: The CSS flex-shrink property specifies the flex shrink factor of a flex item.

I also tried to tinker with the sandboxes http://demo.agektmr.com/flexbox/ and http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/ linked on MDN but I still wasn't enlightned.

Can you elaborate some explanation on those properties to help understand their meaning?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the specification?  http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/CR-css3-flexbox-20120918/.  Also related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14224732/in-what-circumstances-flex-shrink-is-applied-to-the-flex-elements-and-how-it-wor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @cimmanon in the comments, the w3 specification explains it much better: http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/CR-css3-flexbox-20120918/#flex:

In short:

**flex-basis** specifies the *initial main size* of the flex item, before free space is distributed according to the flex factors.

**flex-grow** controls the distribution of *positive* free space (when the size of the container is bigger than the size required to display the flex items)

**flex-shrink** controls the distribution of *negative* space (when the container dimension is less than the size required to display the items)