# CSS3 flexbox adjust height of vertically aligned elements

Tags: css, flexbox

Is it possible to make `.item-1` height flexible and adjust `.item-2` height? For example:

- if `.item-1` height is `10%` then `.item-2` height is `90%`
- if `.item-1` height is `11%` then `.item-2` height is `89%`

So depending on the content of the `.item-1` we should resize it.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item item-1">1</div>
    <div class="item item-2">2</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html,
body,
.container {
    height: 100%;
}
.container {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-flex-flow: column;
    -moz-flex-flow: column;
    -ms-flex-flow: column;
    flex-flow: column;
}
.item {
    background: #eee;
    margin: 1px;
}
.item-1 {
  -webkit-box-flex: 3 3 100%;
  -moz-box-flex: 3 3 100%;
  -webkit-flex: 3 3 100%;
  -ms-flex: 3 3 100%;
  flex: 3 3 100%;
}
.item-2 {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1 1 100%;
  -moz-box-flex: 1 1 100%;
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 100%;
  -ms-flex: 1 1 100%;
  flex: 1 1 100%;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vpetrychuk/SYZtg/2

Comment: Related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14224732/in-what-circumstances-flex-shrink-is-applied-to-the-flex-elements-and-how-it-wor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with the 2009 Flexbox properties because there is nothing comparable to the `flex-basis` property (the `box-flex` property from the 2009 draft is not the same thing as the `flex` property from the modern draft, as it can only accept a single floating point value rather than 0-2 integers and 0-1 lengths).

http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/AGLge

```
html,
body,
.container {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.item {
  background: #eee;
  margin: 1px;
}

.item-1 {
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 10%;
  -ms-flex: 1 1 10%;
  flex: 1 1 10%;
}

.item-2 {
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 90%;
  -ms-flex: 1 1 90%;
  flex: 1 1 90%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's sad that we cannot avoid percentages :( Could you suggest some workaround?

Comment: I do not want to hardcode `.item-1` height to `10%`. Its height should depend on the content inside it. And `.item-2` height should also be flexible `100% - .item-1 height`.

Comment: It *is* flexible.  See the question I linked to above.  The `flex-basis` property is simply the element's ideal size.  It isn't the same thing as specifying `width`.